# NAnt build failure

Tags: nant

I keep getting this NAnt error, please advise...

`The type System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\...' and '...\\my Project folder path'`

I have tried everything...reinstalling NAnt, VS, verifying build file,etc.

I tried deleting that dll from my project folder. It then complains about {get; set} methods.

I even tried uninstalling .net 2.0 because that is what is causing all the problems, but that doesn't work since .net 2.0 folder cannot be deleted...

If it has to be deleted, i will have to mess with the registry, which i dont want to because I have specifics in there that I dont want to disturb.

Thanks in advance!!
Cheers!!

Comment: Could you provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not have figured this out in a million years. One of my peers helped me with this one.

Solution:

1. Try to download NAnt (its a zipped folder)
2. Before you extract the folder  you should right click on the zip file then select Properties and under the General tab, click the button labelled Unblock, then click OK on the Properties window.
3. Once you do that, extract the file to your desired location

4.Now change the path in your environmental variables

5.Open a new command Prompt and run NAnt

End of all problems...NAnt works awesome!!

Thanks!!